# DataStax Trouble with Creating Job Tracker

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise

I downloaded DataStax Enterprise and I was trying to run the following thier Portfolio Example (www.datastax.com/docs/datastax_enterprise2.2/solutions/dse_demo#dse-demo) but I got stuck. The issue I am having is that I can't get start the job tracker on a node.

I am using version 3.0.1 of dse on Ubuntu. I also have it set up with a single node, since I am just using one machine. I have already started a node and have both the opscenterd and opscenter-agent running.

When I run:

> dse cassandra -t -j

I get the following output:

> xss =  -ea -javaagent:/usr/share/dse/cassandra/lib/jamm-0.2.5.jar -XX:+UseThreadPriorities -XX:ThreadPriorityPolicy=42 -Xms1024M -Xmx1024M -Xmn200M -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xss180k
>
> Error: Exception thrown by the agent : java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 7199; nested exception is:
>      java.net.BindException: Address already in use

When try and use dsetool instead:

> dsetool movejt localhost

I see, in log/cassandra/system.log, that if fails because:

> Caused by: InvalidRequestException(why:Keyspace dse_system does not exist)
>
> ```
>  at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.ThriftValidation.validateTable(ThriftValidation.java:83)
>  at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.ThriftValidation.validateColumnFamily(ThriftValidation.java:135)
>  at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.statements.SelectStatement$RawStatement.prepare(SelectStatement.java:973)
>  at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.QueryProcessor.getStatement(QueryProcessor.java:243)
>  at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.QueryProcessor.processInternal(QueryProcessor.java:129)
>  at com.datastax.bdp.hadoop.mapred.TrackerManager.queryForJobTrackers(TrackerManager.java:202)
>  at com.datastax.bdp.hadoop.mapred.TrackerManager.getJTNodes(TrackerManager.java:170)
> ```

What could be causing this? And how can it be fixed?

Comment: can you restart your server? If, clear /var/lib/cassandra/data/ directory and then start the server

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you have started up DSE as a plain C* node.
To verify run:  `nodetool ring` and `dsetool ring` and you will see the workload Cassandra for your node

The reason I believe this is because:
1) you have port in use error indicating you have a c* service already started
2) dse_system only gets created when you start up as a hadoop node, -t

To work around this, kill all java processes and try to restart with the -t option.  It should detect that you dse_system has not been created and then create it.  Then verify with `dsetool ring`.

Answer (score 0):

The above worked for me. Errors thrown were:

```
$ dse pig
Error when fetching jobtracker address: 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could
$ dsetool jobtracker
Error when fetching jobtracker address: 
java.io.IOException: Could not find Job Tracker.
```

To resolve I did the following:

```
$ dse cassandra-stop
$ dse cassandra -t
```